# the counter increases the value 100 times vuejs

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

I recently started learning wuejs. There was a task to get data from api, add it to the array and display the blocks with the date attribute through v-for. But I have the following output

ДИЕТА 600

dfhgsdfghdfgh 601

fghdfghdfghd 602

dfghdfghdfgh 603

dfghdfghdfghdfgh 604

dftghdfghdfghdfghfgh 605

(Right value counter)

C increasing the size of the array by 1 counter increases by 100, that is, if you add one element to the array next to each line, the values ​​from 700 will be

CONSOLE:
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

(found in )

I’ve seen a way with @, but the Razor syntax is bothering me, I don’t know how to connect them. And maybe this is not the problem. Help

html

```
<div id="axiostest">
        <div v-for="item in message"  :data-testid="counter">
            <p class="text-danger">{{ item }} {{ counter++}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

vuejs

```
var axios = new Vue({
            el: '#axiostest',
            data: {
                message: [],
                counter: 0
            },
            methods: {

            },
            mounted() {
                axios
                    .get('/Profile/GetLastChallenge', {
                        params: {
                            userEmail: '@User.Identity.Name'
                        }
                    })
                    .then(response => (this.message = response.data));
            }
        });
```

Comment: render triggers `counter++` triggers render triggers `counter++` triggers render triggers and so on. same can be done with `v-for="(item, index) in message"`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is on your `{{ counter++ }}`, if you want to show the counter plus 1 try `{{ counter + 1}}` this wont trigger the render.
And for a good and safe code, every time you use v-for to loop something, use a key directive so VueJs wont lose itself during the loop, something like:

`<div v-for="(item, i) in message"  :data-testid="counter" :key="item">
      <p class="text-danger">{{ item }} {{ counter + 1 }}</p>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to just output the array you can use this:

```html
<div id="axiostest">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in message"  :data-testid="index">
        <p class="text-danger">{{ item }} {{ index }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can do something you want with index^ {{index + 1}}, {{index * 2 }}, etc

And, as Estradiaz said, you get warn because counter++ occurs rerender